# designer file is listed separately form main class file

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, solution, filetree

I have a UIViewController classes that has its own designer file but designer file is not shown as a sub-tree element in solution panel (GameScreen). On the other hand, second UIViewController (SettingsScreen) designer file is shown as a child to main class.

Usually designer files should be shown as sub object. what went wrong and how can I fix it?

the code compiles correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MonoDevelop doesn't currently have a drag-n-drop way to alter file groupings, but there are two other ways you can do this:

a) Remove the files from the project and add them back. For certain files, such as MonoTouch designer files, MD will automatically group them when they're added.

b) Edit the csproj file, and add  metadata to the child file. You can use this to create arbitrary groupings.

If you can recall how the designer was was added without being grouped, and can reproduce the issue, please [file a bug.](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com)